# How to make a card slider with json data

Tags: javascript, json, slider, card

I'm trying to make a card slider with json data like this: http://femkreations.com/projects/ajax/ajax-carousel/index.php and instead I want to use json data from this url: https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/breeds to display 5 cards with the name, discription and image from the cats. I already loaded the json data with the XMLHttpRequest, but I don't really know what I need to do from now. I'm a beginner at these things and I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to define the template to be used according to your own JSON data
Let's say your JSON looks like this for simplification's sake

```
{
  cats: [

       {
        name: "rico",
        power_level: "500",
        bio: "nice dude"
       },
       {
        name: "johnnyboi",
        power_level: "1200",
        bio: "bad guy"  
       },
       {
        name: "earl",
        power_level: "over9000",
        bio: "stronk guy"
       }
     ]
}
```

this guy defines the template in HTML code like this (somewhere in between the HTML code). Note that you will have to work or copy the CSS class speaker.

```
<script id="speakerstpl" type="text/template">
{{#speakers}}
    <div class="speaker">
        <img src="images/{{shortname}}_tn.jpg" alt="Photo of {{name}}" />
        <h3>{{name}}</h3>
        <h4>{{reknown}}</h4>
        <p>{{bio}}</p>
    </div>
{{/speakers}}
</script>
```

So let's adapt the template the way you want to have for the JSON I wrote above:

```
<script id="speakerstpl" type="text/template">
{{#cats}}
    <div class="speaker">            
        <h3>{{name}}</h3>
        <h4>{{power_level}}</h4>
        <p>{{bio}}</p>
    </div>
{{/cats}}
</script>
```

Now, before we use the magic behind the functions, note that this page is using the following external libraries (don't forget to add them into your document):

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle/2.9999.8/jquery.cycle.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/0.7.0/mustache.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Let's do the calls:

```
var data = {
  cats: [

       {
        name: "rico",
        power_level: "500",
        bio: "nice dude"
       },
       {
        name: "johnnyboi",
        power_level: "1200",
        bio: "bad guy"  
       },
       {
        name: "earl",
        power_level: "over9000",
        bio: "stronk guy"
       }
     ]
}

var template = $('#speakerstpl').html();
var html = Mustache.to_html(template,data);
$('#carousel').html(html); //this element is a div inside another div (wrapper)
//final step for the rotation/cycle
$('#carousel').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        pause: 1,
        next: '#next_btn',
        prev: '#prev_btn',
        speed: 500,
        timeout: 10000
    });
```

EDIT: Here a simple code from https://developpaper.com/xmlhttprequest-for-asynchronous-requests/ in order to get your data by the way:

```
var data = {cats: []};
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
method = "GET",
url = "https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/breeds";

xhr.open(method, url, true);
xhr.responseType = "json";
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

if(xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
  if (xhr. status === 200) {// successful request
    console.log(xhr.response);
    //capture this response using your data variable
    data.cats = xhr.response;
     
  } else {// request failed
      console.log(xhr.response);
  }    
 }
};
xhr.ontimeout = function(event){
console.log('request timeout!');
}
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
xhr.send();
```